# Can a data list be used to show different repeat columns based on what value is selected from a dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, datalist, listitem

1) Can a DataList be used to show different repeat columns based on what value is selected from a DropDown? So, for example, if a DropDown's value is selected to be 4, can all rows in a DataList be set to 4 rows horizontally?

2) Is there are way for a ItemList or Repeater to do dynamic horizontal display of data?
For example, either all rows are same:

- xxxx
- xxxx
- xxxx

or, each row is different:

- xxxx
- xx
- xxxxxx

Comment: You could use nested repeaters. Use the outer one to generate the rows. The inner one could get its DataSource dynamically from a function.

Comment: Do you want a code sample ..? is so what are is the field name of the DataSource you would like to display .. what is the DataList Bound to...?

Comment: Consider ListView, much more flexible

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, you can set the default repeat properties of the DataList to what you need,  then add an OnSelectedIndexChange event to the DropDownList.  Basic example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        DataList1.RepeatColumns = 4; //Initial Rows
        DataList1.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = DataList1.RepeatColumns.ToString();
        //LoadDataList;
    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataList1.RepeatColumns = Convert.ToInt16(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    //LoadDataList;
}
```